# Basic I/O (reading and outputof lines in C

Tags: c, io, c-strings

I am writing a basic C program to read a line.

But when I run it and enter text in the terminal, it does not output anything. I feel I may not be using getchart()/putchar() properly but I am not sure. **Is getchar()/putchar() the reason nothing is being output?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

// function to read a line
void read_line(char *line, int max_len) {
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar() != EOF) && i < max_len) {
        line[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';

}

int main()
{
    char line[100];
    read_line(line, 100);
    printf("%s\n", line);

}
```

Comment: If you're reading lines, it is conventional to look for the newline at the end of the line — yet there is no mention of `'\n'` in the `read_line()` function — which is surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems in your function. Corrected (with comments) below...

```
void read_line(char *line, int max_len) {
    int i = 0;

    // EOF is an int... Need an int
    // char c;
    int c;

    // misplaced parenthesis
    //while ( (c = getchar() != EOF) && i < max_len) {

    // What happens when user types too much?
    // 'i' will be beyond the array end.
    // while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && i < max_len) {

    // Detect enter of NL ("return") (rearranged somewhat)
    // while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && i < max_len - 1) {

    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF && i < max_len - 1) {
        line[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
}
```

You could account for the buffer overrun by declaring this way in main():

```
char line[ 100 + 1 ];
read_line( line, 100 );
```

Not the most elegant, but sufficient for now...

Comment: Where does the code look for a newline?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point... Fixing immediately. Thanks... Overlooked trying to post the other corrections. Thanks again...